# calculus question about finding a limit of a sequence of functions.

Tags: calculus

Let $$f_n = n \chi_{[0,\frac{1}{n} ]}$$

I want to find $ \lim f_n$. I think it is $0$ since if we fix $x$ then can find $x > \frac{1}{N} $ By archimedes. So $f_n(x) $ must be $0$ for all $n > N$ is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like $f_n(x)$ approaches $0$ for each positive $x$, is $0$ for any negative $x$, and approaches $\infty$ for $x=0$.  Since $f_n(0) = n \chi_{[0,n^{-1}]}(0) = n\cdot 1 = n$ we have the sequence $\{1,2,3,4,\ldots\}$.